# Unit test after upgrading the Spring Boot version hasOnlyOneElementSatisfying() method is not working

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit, assertj

Unit test was working fine in its previous version while after updating the version it shows error

```
public class PersonSearchUtil {
    private final HashSet<SearchResponse> result = new HashSet<>();
    .
    .
    .
    public HashSet<SearchResponse> getResult() {
            return result;
    }
}
```

**Test Method**

```
@Test
fun `When person id is all zeroes, should merge`() {
    val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
    add() {
        eeId = "same eeId"
        personId = UUID(0,0)
    }
    add() {
        eeId = "same eeId"
        personId = uuid
    }

    assertThat(service.result)
            .hasSize(1)
            .hasOnlyOneElementSatisfying { response ->.  // hasOnlyOneElementSatisfying is deprecated 
                assertThat(response.eeId).isEqualTo("same eeId")  // shows Unresolved reference: eeId 
                assertThat(response.personId).isEqualTo(uuid)  // shows Unresolved reference: personId
            }
}
```

**Error:**

Unresolved reference: eeId

Unresolved reference: personId

Comment: Could you please provide the class definition of `SearchResponse`?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#hasOnlyOneElementSatisfying(java.util.function.Consumer)), [`singleElement()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#singleElement()) should be used instead.

Also, there is a known issue with Kotlin and recent versions of AssertJ ([assertj/assertj-core#2439](https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/2439)).

One of the following workarounds might solve your issue until that gets addressed in AssertJ:

```
assertThat(service.result as Iterable<SearchResponse>)
    .hasSize(1)
    .hasOnlyOneElementSatisfying { response ->
        assertThat(response.eeId).isEqualTo("same eeId")
        assertThat(response.personId).isEqualTo(uuid)
    }
}
```

```
CollectionAssert(service.result)
    .hasSize(1)
    .hasOnlyOneElementSatisfying { response ->
        assertThat(response.eeId).isEqualTo("same eeId")
        assertThat(response.personId).isEqualTo(uuid)
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked! In case you can provide the definition of `SearchResponse`, I could add an example with `singleElement()`.